# How should I pass this variable E to this class? Custom serializer GSON

Tags: java, generics, serialization, gson, azure-mobile-services

I am following [this](http://hashtagfail.com/post/44606137082/mobile-services-android-serialization-gson) tutorial in order to implement a custom serializer in Windows Azure Mobile Android. I am trying to use the code however I am getting an error with E variable.

```
public class CollectionSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Collection>, JsonDeserializer<Collection>{

public JsonElement serialize(Collection collection, Type type,
                             JsonSerializationContext context) {
    JsonArray result = new JsonArray();
    for(E item : collection){
        result.add(context.serialize(item));
    }
    return new JsonPrimitive(result.toString());
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Collection deserialize(JsonElement element, Type type,
                              JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonArray items = (JsonArray) new JsonParser().parse(element.getAsString());
    ParameterizedType deserializationCollection = ((ParameterizedType) type);
    Type collectionItemType = deserializationCollection.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    Collection list = null;

    try {
        list = (Collection)((Class<?>) deserializationCollection.getRawType()).newInstance();
        for(JsonElement e : items){
            list.add((E)context.deserialize(e, collectionItemType));
        }
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        throw new JsonParseException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new JsonParseException(e);
    }

    return list;
}
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'E'

Comment: Of course you haven't declared any type parameter in your method. That method is not generic. So, `E` cannot be resolved. Why are you typecasting to `E` at all?

Comment: Because I am not sure on the type of the collection that will be passed.

Comment: I am new to Java so I am not sure about this should be done. I am going to try it without the type casting and see if it works.

Comment: You can learn about generics [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You possibly meant to declare your class like this:

```
public class CollectionSerializer<E> implements JsonSerializer<Collection<E>>,
                                                JsonDeserializer<Collection<E>> {
```

The first method could then become:

```
public JsonElement serialize(Collection<E> collection, Type type,
                             JsonSerializationContext context) {
    JsonArray result = new JsonArray();
    for(E item : collection){
        result.add(context.serialize(item));
    }
    return new JsonPrimitive(result.toString());
}
```

Alternatively, you can leave the class declaration as is and change your method to:

```
public <E> JsonElement serialize(Collection<E> collection, Type type,
                             JsonSerializationContext context) {
    JsonArray result = new JsonArray();
    for(E item : collection){
        result.add(context.serialize(item));
    }
    return new JsonPrimitive(result.toString());
}
```

Which one you need depends on your use case (whether a given `CollectionSerializer` always expects the same type of collection or not).